# Array Formula To Find 2nd Largest Number

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I currently use the following formula to find the largest number in a dataset (Sheet1K7:K106), conditional on some corresponding values (Sheet2!C7:C106) being less than a certain number (Sheet3!C18):

```
=MAX(Sheet1!K7:K106*(Sheet2!C7:C106<Sheet3!C18))
```

I would like to now find the second largest number given the same condition. I would assume that this requires the LARGE function, although I can't seem to apply the aforementioned condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Excel 2010 or later:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,Sheet1!K7:K106/(Sheet2!C7:C106<Sheet3!C18),2)
```

Otherwise, **array formula****:

```
=LARGE(IF(Sheet2!C7:C106<Sheet3!C18,Sheet1!K7:K106),2)
```

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*